# Solving linear system by triangular decomposition using C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

I trying to solve a linear system by triangular decomposition using C++

this is the requirements, anybody can help me, please...

[image]

[image: and this is the example of input and output]

Comment: [Why is "someone can help me?"  not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [Solving linear equations with Gaussian elimination](https://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/)?